# How to get location from user who sent a message to bot Python telegram bot API without

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I Have that code

**main.py**

```
import telebot

bot_token = "my_token"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["send_location"])
def sendlocation(message):
    print(message.location)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

When I sent the command (/send_location) to my bot in telegram with turned on location in my phone I get that:

```
None
```

Why I get None information about location and what should I do that I want to get location? (don't propose me use button, only by command)

Comment: Not possible afaik. The message.location field will only contain a non-None value when request_location is set to True, which can be done by keyboard button.